# Transfer values of 3 dimensional from one array to another based on value

Tags: php, arrays

If the workgroup_id matches, I want to get the remaining key and values from the 2nd array. Is this possible?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 10
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 8
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [workgroup_id] => 5
                )

        )

)


Array
(
    [774] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 25
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 10
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 774
                    ['order_id'] => 1
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 1
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 10
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 774
                    ['order_id'] => 2
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 6
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 10
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 774
                    ['order_id'] => 3
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

        )

    [775] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 25
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 1
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 775
                    ['order_id'] => 1
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 10
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 1
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 775
                    ['order_id'] => 2
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 8
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 1
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 775
                    ['order_id'] => 3
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    ['workgroup_id'] => 1
                    ['assigned_quantity'] => 1
                    ['completed_quantity'] => 0
                    ['date_completed'] => 
                    ['production_id'] => 775
                    ['order_id'] => 4
                    ['production_workgroup_remarks'] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But SO is a service, where people will help you solve a problem with your code, not write your code for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried different array functions but can't find the exact one. echo '<pre>';
 print_r(array_replace_recursive($arrayA,$arrayB));
 echo '</pre>';